# ng-include is displayed as a comment

Tags: angularjs

I am trying add a template inside a google maps infowindow but when i try to compile the content and set it to `infowindow.content`, it is displayed as a comment. I am using the version `1.2.27`.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var content = '<div id="iw_c" ng-include="\'/infowindow.html\'"></div>';
var compiled = $compile(content)(scope);
infowindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
console.log(infowindow.content);
```

And this is the output from `console.log(infowindow.content)`

```
<!-- ngInclude: '/infowindow.html' -->
```

Already tried the solution in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160008/ng-include-compiles-to-a-comment).

Comment: you need to wrap the path in single quotes.try this `<div ng-include src="'infowindow.html'"></div>`

Comment: The `(\)` is to escape `(')` from the content `(')`. But even if I put `'<div ng-include=""></div>'` I get the same output.

Comment: FYI http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14226975/angularjs-ng-include-inside-of-google-maps-infowindow

Comment: The problem was in the version. Works fine in 1.1.5

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know why but putting a div before ng-include div solved the problem.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var content = '<div><div id="iw_c" ng-include="\'/infowindow.html\'"></div></div>';
var compiled = $compile(content)(scope);
infowindow.setContent(compiled[0]);
console.log(infowindow.content);
```